# 3gp file not playing audio in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, html5-audio, 3gp

I have a 3gp file I'm trying to display and play in chrome browser. It seems to play the video fine but the audio is not playing...When I download the file on my machine the audio and video plays fine..When I open the video in a standalone chrome tab it plays the video but does not play the audio. In the image note how the audio button is greyed out.

html code:

```
<video src="/media/somefilesentfrommyiphone.3gp" style="max-width:400px;" controls=""></video>
```

[image: Note how the audio is not present]

note the video and audio seem to play just fine in safari

Comment: If you can share an example video link it will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Check the codecs in the 3GP file. Most likely the audio format is not supported by Chrome. Use a tool like **MediaInfo** to check audio type. PS: What's wrong with using MP4 with AAC audio to get a "most browsers" playback? 3GP might have limited support (I'm surprised it actually plays anything in Chrome).